# FromBody annotation is not able to access field from request body

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I created a sample .NET Core Web API and provide an endpoint to create a new task for yourself. So the endpoint would be

> POST ...baseUrl.../me/tasks

The method for this is

```
    [HttpPost("tasks")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<Task>> CreateUserTaskAsync([FromBody] CreateUserTaskBodyDto createUserTaskBodyDto)
    {
        // ...
    }
```

As you can see the parameter is a DTO which deals with the request validation for the body. This DTO currently has one field but there might be more fields later on

```
public class CreateUserTaskBodyDto
{
    [Range(1, 30)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

When calling the url with the following body

```
{
    "name": "abc"
}
```

I get a 400 with the error

```
"errors": {
    "Name": [
        "The field Name must be between 1 and 30."
    ]
}
```

(I also tried it by renaming "name" to "Name"). I'm testing the API with Postman, this screenshot shows my request setup

[image]

Does someone know what's wrong or missing here?

Comment: it seems you trying to check Name length with Range attribute? this is wrong. Range validates value itself, not its length

Comment: oh damn ... didn't know that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you remove the

> [Range(1, 30)]

attribute it should work

Also if you want to validate the length of the name property you should use StringLenghtAttribute

```
[StringLength(30, MinimumLength = 1, ErrorMessage = "Name must be between 3 and 50 character in length.")]
```

Answer (score 1):

According to Microsoft docs [Range Attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.rangeattribute?view=netcore-3.1)
Range attribute specifies the numeric range constraints for the value of a data field.

If you want to specify max and min string length. See [MinLengthAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.minlengthattribute?view=netcore-3.1)

```
[MinLength(1)]
[MaxLength(30)]
public string Name { get; set; }
```